# Solving three impedances in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance

I have a circuit of two capacitors and three resitors, where two pairs of the components are in parallel combinations:

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the total impedance.

Since \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$ are in parallel and likewise \$C_2\$ and \$R_2\$ i would think the solution would be:

\$Z_E = R_1 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_1} + R_2 + \frac{1}{j\omega C_2} + R_3\$

However my textbook tells me that the answer is what's given on the picture.

Can anyone clarify this for me? Thank you.

Comment: This kind of conceptual error happens when a professor gets to talking too fast. Capacitance in parallel is added to form a larger overall capacitance, but when analyzing parallel _impedance_, bear in mind that you are effectively looking at a resistor network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's translate your words into an equation for the equivalent impedance.

> Since C1 and R1 are in parallel

$$Z_1 = R_1||\frac{1}{sC_1}$$

> likewise C2 and R2

$$Z_2 = R_2||\frac{1}{sC_2}$$

> Solving three impedances in series

$$Z_E = Z_1 + Z_2 + R_3$$

Comment: Thank you Alfred. It seems obvious now, but was kinda confused.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on another Answer.

> Since C1 and R1 are in parallel

$$Z_1 = R_1||\frac{1}{sC_1}$$

$$Z_1 = \frac{R_1 \cdot \frac{1}{s \ C_1}}{R_1 + \frac{1}{s \ C_1}} = \frac{R_1}{1+s \ C_1 \ R_1}$$

> likewise C2 and R2

$$Z_2 = \frac{R_2}{1+s \ C_2 \ R_2}$$

> Solving three impedances in series

$$Z = \frac{R_1}{1+s \ C_1 \ R_1} + \frac{R_2}{1+s \ C_2 \ R_2} + R_3$$

Comment: Thank you Warren. I don't know which answer to accept now. Your answer is a direct answer to my question, but Alfreds clarification solved my problem..

Comment: Accept either one Id probably go with Alfred's as he was first though and I haven't added much except to give a final formula.